# How do I use the JAVA_OPTS environment variable?

Tags: java, jvm

How do I use the `JAVA_OPTS` variable to configure a web server (a linux server)?

How can I set `-Djava.awt.headless=true` using `JAVA_OPTS`?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`JAVA_OPTS` is the standard environment variable that some servers and other java apps append to the call that executes the `java` command.

For example in tomcat if you define `JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1024m'`, the startup script will execute `java org.apache.tomcat.Servert -Xmx1024m`

If you are running in Linux/OSX, you can set the JAVA_OPTS, right before you call the startup script by doing

```
JAVA_OPTS='-Djava.awt.headless=true'
```

This will only last as long as the console is open.
To make it more permanent you can add it to your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: if you run Spring boot fully executable jar, you could by this to specify -D property, e.g. JAVA_OPTS="-Dspring.profiles.active=test" ./myapp.jar

Answer (score 23):

Just figured it out in Oracle Java the environmental variable is called: `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`
rather than `JAVA_OPTS`

Answer (score 19):

`JAVA_OPTS` is environment variable used by tomcat in its startup/shutdown script to configure params.

You can set it in linux by

```
export JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

Answer (score 5):

`JAVA_OPTS` is not restricted to Tomcat’s Java process, but passed to all JVM processes running on the same machine.

Use `CATALINA_OPTS` if you specifically want to pass JVM arguments to Tomcat's servlet engine.

Comment: This is not strictly correct.  A lot of "JVM processes" pay no attention to $JAVA_OPTS at all.  For instance, none of the Oracle java commands, Apache "mvn", Apache "ant", ...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can, even though accepted answer saying that you can't.

There is a `_JAVA_OPTIONS` environment variable, more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts)

Answer (score -1):

As stated in these links below, you can edit JAVA_OPTS for Wildfly/JBoss in bin/standalone.conf

- [How to increase heap memory for WildFly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959128/how-to-increase-heap-memory-for-wildfly)
- [Configuring JVM Settings](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/configuring_jvm_settings)