# How to increase heap memory for WildFly?

Tags: java, performance, wildfly, heap-memory

WildFly 8 is started on a linux server with standalone.sh. I noticed that the server was started with very few heap memory space.

I need to increase the heap memory space for the server and for applications, which are running on the server. How can I do it?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Just edit `bin/standalone.conf`, look for the first occurrence of `JAVA_OPTS` and change the `-Xmx` option according to your needs.

Comment: Do you need to restart Wildfly?

Comment: Yes, a restart is required.

Comment: Better look for what message is prompted when launching the server. It will tell you which conf file is loaded. In my case, on windows, it was prompting: "Calling "<path_to_wildfly>\wildfly-10.0.0\bin\standalone.conf.bat"". Therefore, I find the answer from Dulith more useful.

Answer (score 27):

**Linux**:

```
bin/standalone.conf
```

Check for the following line,

```
JAVA_OPTS
```

and change it accordingly to suit your **heap size needs**

```
-Xms1303m: initial heap size in megabytes
-Xmx1303m: maximum heap size in megabytes

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048M"
```

**Windows**:

```
bin/standalone.conf.bat

JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1024M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=2048M -XX:MaxHeapSize=2048M"
```

Now **restart** the server and it will work without prompting any heap size errors.

Comment: For windows this solution works, this file is used in windows: `bin/standalone.conf.bat`

Answer (score 16):

On `OS WINDOWS` you need to setting `standalone.conf.bat`

Answer (score 6):

if wildfly 8 is used along with JDK 8,
We need to add MaxMetaSpace Size.
For example,
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256M"
As we all know Java 8 does not support Perm gen setting.
For related information, Please check 
[Wildfly Heap issue](http://techno-terminal.blogspot.in/2017/03/wildfly-82-heap-issue.html)

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

I am running Eclipse and changing the 'bin/standalone.conf' didn’t work for me. In this case the solution was oppening the 'Servers' view in Eclipse, double-click the Wildfly server, go to 'Open launch configuation' and do that changes there in 'VM argumments'. Anyway I am a bit noob with Wildfly, I hope other users could contrast my info, I found that in http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/articles-wildfly-jvmparams

Its for a Linux server, but I think it could work for windows too.

Answer (score 5):

For managed domain you can set it using `heap` tag (e.g.`<heap size="64m" max-size="512m"/>`) within `jvm` in domain.xml or host.xml (depending on the scope you want to address).

Answer (score 3):

Answer from [official documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY10/JVM+settings):

> For a standalone server, you have to pass in the JVM settings either
>   as command line arguments when executing the
>   `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.sh` script, or by declaring them in
>   `$JBOSS_HOME/bin/standalone.conf`. (For Windows users, the script to
>   execute is `%JBOSS_HOME%/bin/standalone.bat` while the JVM settings can
>   be declared in `%JBOSS_HOME%/bin/standalone.conf.bat`)

** Restart server to make this change effective.