# How can I convert a String in ASCII(Unicode Escaped) to Unicode(UTF-8) if I am reading from a file?

Tags: java, unicode, encoding, utf-8, escaping

**EDIT:**

I am reading that string from a file, so this topic is actually about the following question:

I have this string which is the *equal()* to the one received from the file:

```
"Diogo Pi\\u00e7arra - Tu E Eu"
```

How can I make Java read the resulting string "\u00e7" as a "ç" character?

This happens because the file is not encoded in UTF-8 but in escaped Unicode, hence the reason why I am reading "\u00e7" as a string and not a Unicode character. So I need a function that parses this at runtime. I could iterate over .replace() functions to parse this but......

---

**Old Question (asked in the wrong way before I understand what was going on, please ignore the following text):**

I have the following string:

```
final String str = "Diogo Pi\u00e7arra - Tu E Eu";
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
"Diogo Piçarra - Tu E Eu"
```

I have tried everything, from Apache Lang tools unescape function, to

```
new String(str.getBytes("UTF-16"), "UTF-16")
```

or

```
new String(str.getBytes("UTF-8"), "UTF-8")
```

or

```
new String(str.getBytes("UTF-16"))
```

or

```
new String(str.getBytes("UTF-8"))
```

But nothing works...!

What can I try next?

Thanks!

Comment: What value of `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` are you getting?

Comment: this: ANSI_X3.4-1968

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
final String str = new String("Diogo Pi\u00e7arra - Tu E Eu".getBytes(), 
                              Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

**Result:**

[image]

Try to use `getBytes()` method without parameters (`defaultCharset` will be used here). But it's not necessary. The conversion is not required:

```
final String str = "Diogo Pi\u00e7arra - Tu E Eu";
```

You'll have same result.

Comment: It is not working in my machine, however it works in IDEONE, even without doing that conversion: http://ideone.com/B3dwD9

Comment: I believe I am receiving an escaped string, the equivalent to my situation would be something like this I guess "Diogo Pi\\u00e7arra - Tu E Eu" (notice the double \). I am reading that string from a file, the file does not contain \\ but the \uXXXX is not interpreted as a special unicode character.

Comment: @PedroD, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25548646/wrong-file-encoding-in-jvm-after-linux-update). You have an encoding error in JVM.

Comment: @PedroD, thereafter, tell me of results

Comment: Ok, now it returns utf-8 instead of ANSI_X3.4-1968 by adding the flag -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 to my java command, but the error persists. The problem is that I am reading an escaped string from a file (which I cannot change). What I am reading is the equivalent as "Diogo Pi\\u00e7arra - Tu E Eu". What I need to do is to force Java to read the string "\u00e7" as a unicode special character. I could do with with a .replace() but that would be reinventing the wheel I guess...

Comment: This answer's example has gone offline, but they seem to tackle this exact issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537706/howto-unescape-a-java-string-literal-in-java

Comment: In the end I need to implement this in Java lol: http://www.rapidmonkey.com/unicodeconverter/reverse.jsp

Comment: I found a way to do it with StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(). However I **MUST** read from the file char by char (int, using read() method), and append it to a StringBuilder the following way *sb.append(new String(new byte[] { c }, "UTF-8"))*, then I preform *StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(sb.toString());*.

Comment: This answer is wrong for multiple reasons: 1. in Java source `"\u00e7"` and `"ç"` are identical in every aspect 2. `getBytes()` is locale-dependent and might irreversibly mangle data 3. even if the locale uses UTF-8, `new String(x.getBytes(), Charset.forName("UTF-8"))` will always be equal to `x` 4. You should use `StandardCharsets.UTF8` anyway

Answer (score 4):

The way I got it working for me, reading from a file with escaped unicode explicitly written:

```
    BufferedReader reader1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream()));
    byte c;
    while ((c = (byte) reader1.read()) != -1) {
        output.append(new String(new byte[] { c }, "UTF-8"));
    }
    return StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(output.toString());
```

This works because

```
StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava("Diogo Pi\\u00e7arra - Tu E Eu")
results in "Diogo Piçarra - Tu E Eu"
```

Comment: Please mark this as the accepted answer because the currently marked answer doesn't answer the question. Also your question doesn't seem to want UTF-8 because a Java string is UTF-16.