# No such file while indicating application properties using Dockerfile for a Spring Boot jar

Tags: spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm using Docker Compose to create a container for a Spring Boot application.

I'm receiving the following errors when I do `docker-compose up`:

> Recreating backend_springboot ... error
>
> ERROR: for backend_springboot  Cannot start service service: OCI
>   runtime create failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container
>   process caused "exec: \"sh -c java
>   -Dspring.config.location=/application.properties -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar\": stat sh -c java -Dspring.config.location=/application.properties
>   -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar: no such file or directory": unknown
>
> ERROR: for service  Cannot start service service: OCI runtime create
>   failed: container_linux.go:346: starting container process caused
>   "exec: \"sh -c java -Dspring.config.location=/application.properties
>   -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar\": stat sh -c java -Dspring.config.location=/application.properties
>   -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar: no such file or directory": unknown

My structure:

```
├── docker-compose.yml
├── spring-boot
│   ├── Dockerfile
│   ├── application.properties
│   └── backofficeservices-0.0.1.jar
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  service:
    container_name: backend_springboot
    build: ./spring-boot
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    restart: always
```

spring-boot/Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine as gradle

COPY backofficeservices-0.0.1.jar /app.jar

COPY application.properties /application.properties

ENV JAVA_OPTS=""

ENTRYPOINT ["sh -c java -Dspring.config.location=/application.properties -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app.jar"]

EXPOSE 8080
```

As far as I know, the `application.properties` is not found. I will appreciate any help to detect my error.

My goal is to run my Spring Boot app applying the `application.properties` I have there.

Comment: Did you make sure you mounted the file that it says it can't find to the docker container?

Comment: @bturner1273 yes, well, I have added an instruction to copy the file `application.properties` from my machine to the container, is the second instruction at `spring-boot/Dockerfile`.

Comment: huh... in your error message application.properties is spelled aplication.properties. Could it just be that you typed it wrong somewhere and docker is looking for the wrong file?

Comment: @bturner1273 nice catch. I fixed the name but, still receiving the same error.

Comment: Huh try mounting to your running container and CD and ls ing around to see if your files are actually copying as expected

Comment: Just comment/omit the code asking for the file first obviously

Comment: @bturner1273 The container is "restarting" and don't want to change the status to do "exec -it bash". No matter what I do, it's always restarting. I cannot enter inside of it. This is so confusing to me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have specified an ENTRYPOINT using a single "word".  When you launch the container, it is trying to run that as a single "word" – it is looking for a binary named `sh -c java ...`, with spaces and all as part of the filename.  If your command has multiple "words" and you're using the JSON-array form, you have to correctly manually split it up into words yourself.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "java -Dspring.config.location=..."]
```

A Dockerfile CMD and ENTRYPOINT are fairly similar; both provide part of the command the container ultimately runs.  If you only need one of them I'd recommend using CMD instead, for two reasons: it makes it easier to get a debugging shell on the built image `docker run --rm -it myimage /bin/sh`, and there's a fairly standard pattern of using an ENTRYPOINT script to do some initial setup and then `exec "$@"` to run the CMD.

```
CMD ["sh", "-c", "java -Dspring.config.location=..."]
```

If you have this form, Docker can provide the `sh -c ...` wrapper for you.

```
CMD java -Dspring.config.location=...
```

With a little bit more cleanup, that would leave the final Dockerfile something like

```sh
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine
COPY backofficeservices-0.0.1.jar /app.jar
COPY application.properties /application.properties
ENV JAVA_OPTS=""
CMD java \
      -Dspring.config.location=/application.properties \
      -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom \
      $JAVA_OPTS \
      -jar /app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
```

Comment: It's running, thanks a lot my friend. I didn't know all the tricks that you said. Just one question, how can I add the `ENV JAVA_OPTS=""` into the `CMD`? I just need to add it before the `-jar....` line?

Comment: Yes; I added it to my answer.  (I had been under the impression the JVM handles it on its own, but [it's actually used by things like Tomcat startup scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241743/how-do-i-use-the-java-opts-environment-variable) and not the JVM proper.)