# Increase Heap Size for Java server (Increasing JVM Memory of Go Server)

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory, go-cd

I am trying to increase JVM Memory of my Go server.

This is what I see on /etc/default/go-server

```
# Ansible managed
export GO_SERVER_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES="-Dmail.smtp.starttls.enable=true"
export GO_SERVER_PORT=8153
export GO_SERVER_SSL_PORT=8154
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java
export SERVER_WORK_DIR=/var/lib/go-server
export GO_SERVER_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES="$GO_SERVER_SYSTEM_PROPERTIES -Dgo.plugin.build.status.go-server=http://localhost:8153"
```

Any idea how I can add **-Xmx2048m** here for **GO_SERVERSYSPROPS**?

Thanks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5241743/how-do-i-use-the-java-opts-environment-variable

Answer (score 1):

JAVA_OPTS is the standard environment variable that some servers and other java apps append to the call that executes the java command.

```
 JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx2048m'
```

Comment: Thanks, so something like this on the new line at the end -> 
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xmx2048m"